# Flutter:PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am trying to enable my app as admin using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/admin) plugin.

This is my code  below:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();  
    Admin.enable();            
    _callStreamSubscription = phoneStateCallEvent.listen((PhoneStateCallEvent event) {
      print('Call is Incoming or Connected: ' + event.stateC);  
      if(event.stateC=="true"){        
        _invokeNativeMethod("startRecording");
      }
      else if(event.stateC=="false"){        
        _invokeNativeMethod("stopRecording");      
      }
    });   
  }
```

Error is as follows:

```
E/flutter ( 8036): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.app.Activity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, null)
E/flutter ( 8036): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:569:7)
E/flutter ( 8036): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:321:33)
E/flutter ( 8036): <asynchronous suspension>                            
E/flutter ( 8036): #2      Admin.enable (package:admin/admin.dart:10:21)
E/flutter ( 8036): #3      _MyHomePageState.initState (package:automatic_call_recorder/main.dart:55:11)
```

Any help would really be appreciated!!

Comment: This package still in developpement state, maybe he is not ready to use. Contact the creator of the package.

Comment: @Milvintsiss Thanks for reply. I tried running the example and it run fines. Btw got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I got the solution:

Actually, I tried adding the code in my old package where I had platform-specific code in which I had removed this line

```
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
```

Because of which the error was occuring.
So I added the line again and it works fine now.

Comment: Ok, so where exactly did you remove and then re-add this line, plz? :)

Comment: Update: Never mind, I had actually added that line in accordance with the instructions for the package `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3` but now, I have upgraded to `firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14`. So I just undid ALL of those old instructions, removing the `Application.java` file and reversing all the changes to the `AndroiodManifest.xml` etc... and now, my project also works fine! :) So I guess the conclusion here is: Either add or remove that line! ;)

Comment: @KarolinaHagegård Sorry, for late reply. If you are using Java then in android/app/src/main/java/{package_name}/MainActivity.java otherwise, in Kotlin, android/app/src/main/java/{package_name}/MainActivity.kt